# Intellitrace data with vs 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, intellitrace

Is there a link or some way to collect intellitrace data in my app server? I searched on google and there are ways with vs 2012 and later version but I have vs 2010 ultimate and there is no IntelliTraceCollection.cab file in my development machine. I must repro the problem in app server and save that to iTrace files. I don't want to install visual studio in app server, so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the IntelliTrace standalone collector is only available for Visual Studio 2012 or newer and there isn't a good solution for older versions of Visual Studio. If you are able to install VS2012 on at least one machine you can get access to the collector and you would also be able to analyze the resulting itrace file.